# PhpMailer, how do I write the variable value correctly for multiple addCC email address?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a PhpMailer working code as follow: (short version)
(the variable already defined before hand)

```
// Sender and recipient settings
$mail->setFrom($pengirim_email, $pengirim_nama);
$mail->addAddress($untuk_email, $untuk_nama);
$mail->addReplyTo($pengirim_email, $pengirim_nama);
```

Next, I add multiple email address for CC mail:

```
$mail-->addCC('aaa@gmail.com','Abdul');
$mail-->addCC('bbb@gmail.com','Borat');
```

It work as expected.

Now since I'm planning that the email address will come from the SQL query, so for the time being I want to know how do I have to fill the SQL 'CarbonCopy' column table with multiple email addresses - by trying to make a "hardcoded" variable value. So I try like this as the replacement for the `addCC` above:

```
$tembusan="'aaa@gmail.com','Abdul';'bbb@gmail.com','Borat'"; //not working
$CC = explode(';', $tembusan); //not working
for ($i = 0; $i < count($CC); $i++) {$mail->addCC($CC[$i]);} //not working
```

But it throw me an error like this :

> Error in sending email. Mailer Error: Invalid address: (cc):
> 'aaa@gmail.com','Abdul'

So I change the `$tembusan` into like this:

```
$tembusan="aaa@gmail.com,Abdul;bbb@gmail.com,Borat"; //not working
```

It gives me almost the same like the error before:

> Error in sending email. Mailer Error: Invalid address: (cc):
> aaa@gmail.com,Abdul

Next, I try also this kind of code :

```
$tembusan="'aaa@gmail.com','Abdul';'bbb@gmail.com','Borat'"; //not working
$CC = explode(';', $tembusan); //not working
foreach($CC as $CCemail){$mail->AddCC($CCemail;} //not working
```

And it also throw the same error:

> Error in sending email. Mailer Error: Invalid address: (cc):
> 'aaa@gmail.com','Abdul'

If I echo the last code like this `foreach($CC as $CCemail){echo $CCemail. '<br/>';}`, it give me a result like this :

> 'aaa@gmail.com','Abdul' 
> 'bbb@gmail.com','Borat'

In my real code, I have a valid email address. The email address in the code above is just for an example.

Where did I do wrong ?

PS
btw, if I remove the "name" for the email address:

```
$tembusan="aaa@gmail.com;bbb@gmail.com"; //working
$CC = explode(';', $tembusan); //working
foreach($CC as $CCemail){$mail->AddCC($CCemail;} //working
```

it runs as expected (but in the gmail, the CC name is aaa and bbb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do a further explode . try

```
$tembusan="aaa@gmail.com,Abdul;bbb@gmail.com,Borat"; 
$CC = explode(';', $tembusan); 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($CC); $i++) {
$DD = explode(',', $CC[$i]);
$mail->addCC($DD[0], $DD[1]);
}
```

Please note that I have removed the ' characters . (you may use str_replace of PHP to eliminate these characters)